# ant/build.xml:658: null returned: 127

Tags: android, ant, proguard, build.xml

```
cannot run ANT task: 
The following error occurred while executing this line: 
    /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:622: 
The following error occurred while executing this line: 
    /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:658: null returned: 127
```

Lines 621,622:

```
<do-only-if-manifest-hasCode
                elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java">
```

Line 658:

```
proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
```

I've got this error during build of .apk. Can anybody figure out what's wrong ?

Comment: Without knowing the content of those lines? No